# Entity Framework Navigation Collection Property Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two entities as the following:

```
public class FirstEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SecondEntity> SecondEntityCollection { get; set; }
}

public class SecondEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int FirstEntitySomeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SecondEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

My `ModelBuilder` is set as following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FirstEntity>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SecondEntity)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FirstEntitySomeId);
```

When deleting a `FirstEntity` object I do the following:

```
var firstEntity=this.context.FirstEntities.Where(x=>x.Id==someId);
firstEntity.SecondEntityCollection.Clear();
this.context.FirstEntities.Remove(firstEntity);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

However I still get the following exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "....". The conflict occurred in database "Database", table "dbo.SecondEntity", column 'FirstEntitySomeId'.

How can I properly clear the collection before deleting the `firstEntity` object?

It's worth mentioning that I am trying to *avoid* cascade deleting. I do want to delete the orphan entries in the database. However if the best solution/practice is to use cascade delete I will use it.

Is this possible?

Comment: `I am trying to avoid cascade deleting` : is that mean do you need to keep orphan data in the db?

Comment: No, I also want to delete the child entries in the collection. I just am trying to avoid using `WillCascadeOnDelete()` for now. However if this is the best option I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
var firstEntity=this.context.FirstEntities
                       .Where(x=>x.Id==someId)
                       .Include(s => s.SecondEntityCollection);

this.context.FirstEntities.Remove(firstEntity);

foreach (var s in firstEntity.SecondEntityCollection.ToList())
  {
     this.context.SecondEntityCollection.Remove(s);
  }

this.context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `firstEntity.SecondEntityCollection.Count()` is 0 which means that there is no `SecondEntity` children deleted. I can't find out why the `SecondEntityCollection` is empty.

Comment: sorry,I didn't get what you mentioned ? is this working or any issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I was't clear enough. `firstEntity.SecondEntityCollection.ToList()` returns an empty collection - so there is no deleting happening since there are no items inside the `SecondEntityCollection`.

Comment: Worked like a charm,appreciated! :)